# Docker container as CF garden

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to run some test against local container which is Garden like, I want to use docker which should fits our requirement,
is there some docker image /prototype which build as CF garden container ? 
with the FS like `home/vcap/app/.....`  I just want to simulate E2E tests locally without deployment ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking about here, so if this doesn't answer your question please expand your question.  That said, if you're looking for the filesystem or "stack" that's used on CloudFoundry when you `cf push` an app that is currently called `cflinuxfs` and it's based off of Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.

The image itself is maintained as a docker image here -> https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2/.

If you want manually enter the container and work, maybe to run some tests or compile software locally, you can `docker pull cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2` and `docker run cloudfoundry/cflinuxfs2 /bin/bash` and run your tests in the resulting container.  This will give you more control than using `cflocal`, as it will let you spin up a raw docker container with the same file system as an app running on CF and run whatever you want in that container.

If your intent is to run buildpacks inside this container, then you should use the `cflocal` plugin because it will do basically what I said above but also handle running the buildpack in docker container that is created so it's way more convenient.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try CF Local, it should suit your needs for local testing.

https://github.com/sclevine/cflocal

Comment: Thanks I've looked at it , how it can help ? there is a way to use the docker for the container simulation  alone ?

Comment: Can you explain what you are hoping to achieve?